# Kubernetes Pod is not access Service via Name on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I try to learn kubernetes on minikube. I deploy 3 replicas of Nginx via this below yaml.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginxdeployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx
          name: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

Then I try to expose deployments via this yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginxservice
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

Everything is perfect.

```
PS D:\kubernates work> kubectl get all
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f-7rdzv   1/1     Running   0          111m
pod/nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f-8d7n5   1/1     Running   1          111m
pod/nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f-wmvtw   1/1     Running   0          111m

NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          4h51m
service/nginxservice   LoadBalancer   10.110.215.102   <pending>     8080:30903/TCP   70m

NAME                              READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginxdeployment   3/3     3            3           111m

NAME                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f   3         3         3       111m
```

But I try to access service via name from the pod. I am getting this error : Host name could not resolved. I can access over the ip address.

```
PS D:\kubernates work> kubectl exec -it nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f-7rdzv -- /bin/sh
# curl http://10.110.215.102:8080
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

over servicename :

```
PS D:\kubernates work> kubectl exec -it nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f-7rdzv -- /bin/sh
# curl http://nginxservice:8080
**curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nginxservice**
```

dns informations :

```
PS D:\kubernates work> kubectl exec -it nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f-7rdzv -- /bin/sh
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
#
```

enviroment informations:

```
PS D:\kubernates work> kubectl exec -it nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f-7rdzv -- /bin/sh
# env
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
HOSTNAME=nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f-7rdzv
NGINXSERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=10.111.162.61
NGINXSERVICE_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR=10.111.162.61
HOME=/root
NGINXSERVICE_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT=8080
NGINXSERVICE_PORT_8080_TCP_PROTO=tcp
PKG_RELEASE=1~buster
NGINXSERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=8080
NGINXSERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.111.162.61:8080
NGINXSERVICE_PORT_8080_TCP=tcp://10.111.162.61:8080
TERM=xterm
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.96.0.1
NGINX_VERSION=1.19.5
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
NJS_VERSION=0.4.4
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
PWD=/
```

what is the problem ? I am new in kubernetes. Thanks for advice.

for comment @ThanhNguyenVan :

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
default       nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f-7rdzv   1/1     Running   0          170m
default       nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f-8d7n5   1/1     Running   1          170m
default       nginxdeployment-7848d4b86f-wmvtw   1/1     Running   0          170m
kube-system   coredns-f9fd979d6-tqtdh            1/1     Running   2          5h51m
kube-system   etcd-minikube                      1/1     Running   2          5h50m
kube-system   kindnet-ndzcp                      1/1     Running   0          5h8m
kube-system   kindnet-p4hw2                      1/1     Running   1          5h8m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-minikube            1/1     Running   2          5h50m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-minikube   1/1     Running   0          155m
kube-system   kube-proxy-dn9tw                   1/1     Running   0          5h8m
kube-system   kube-proxy-l48px                   1/1     Running   2          5h51m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-minikube            1/1     Running   2          5h50m
kube-system   storage-provisioner                1/1     Running   4          5h51m
```

Comment: can you ping `nginxservice`. in the pod ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan no :(

Comment: can you show `kubectl get pods --all-namespace` ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan ı added the question

Comment: Service name should be `nginxservice.default.svc.cluster.local`can you dig or ping ?

Comment: I tried: curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nginxservice.default.svc.cluster.local

Comment: Have you tried to set up your nginxservice as a NodePort or ClusterIP service ? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport  Also do you have firewalls enabled ?  Also can you try from inside the pod execute nslookup nginxservice.default.svc.cluster.local